# Using custom Font in react native with expo, loading font every time

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo

I am using Expo and the create-react-native app. I enjoy the live/hot reloading feature on my phone, but I'm wondering about custom fonts.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/v17.0.0/guides/using-custom-fonts.html#loading-the-font-in-your-app

The API for Expo only has directions to load them asynchronously. Do I have to do this on every component I want a custom font on? This seems like it would cause some unnecessary calls when I've already loaded it once.

Is there a way to set the font as global or pass it via props once loaded? It seems like they suggest this approach via their last line in that link:

> Note: Typically you will want to load your apps primary fonts before
>   the app is displayed to avoid text flashing in after the font loads.
>   The recommended approach is to move the Font.loadAsync call to your
>   top-level component.

...But they give no explanation on HOW to do that, if that's what they are implying.

So my questions are:

1) Does loading the custom font in multiple times (on each component), cause performance issues? (or maybe it's pulled from cache after the first?)

2) After loading it can you pass the font down via properties or set it as a global?

and finally

3) Is this an Expo only issue? Or a create-react-native app only issue? Or just a livereload/hotloading issue?

Also note, I'm working on Windows/Android

Comment: Alright, so I was a little confused on Expo and its relation with react-native. It seems like modules built on top of react-native which make some things easier, but others a little more difficult. The trade-off being trying to keep developers writing more JS and out of the "weeds" of native code. So that answers #3, this is an Expo only issue. I am not sure if it actually HURTS performance or if you can pass it around, leaving #1 and #2 still open though...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) **You should only load the font once**. As you point out, Expo recommends putting the Font.loadAsync method in the componentDidMount() method of your top-level component.

The performance issue you're referring to is probably the magic that's happening behind the asynchronous call—but again, this should only happen once.

2) **From that point forward, you can use the font in any child component using the "fontFamily" property on `<Text>`**. As their example (which I modified slightly) shows:

First load the font in your top-level component.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Font.loadAsync({
      'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <HelloWorld />
    )
  }
}
```

Then use it in any  component in the app. (Prior to the font loading, you will see the system font - San Francisco on iOS, Roboto on Android. This is why Expo recommends setting a loading state... to avoid awkward flashing between the system font and your newly loaded custom font.)

```
export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'open-sans-bold', fontSize: 56 }}>
      Hello, world!
    </Text>
  }
}
```

3) **This is an Expo-related "issue" (or solution...** depending on how you look at it). For instance, on iOS, adding a custom font involves several steps (adding the font file to your native project, making sure the font shows in your Bundle Resources, adding the font to Info.plist...). Not sure what the process is for Android, but it's something different and probably annoying, too.

Expo has abstracted that away with their Font module, which allows you to do one thing - and get the same result across platforms. Which is pretty cool, in my book.

Comment: I ended up not using it. While I did have to customize the solutions for iOS and Android, they worked better, more global, I felt. My pet peeve was that I was writing code specific for Expo, rather than app related.

Also, I never got the child components to inherit it properly.

Answer (score 1):

To use a font(expo) efficiently you can load the font in the root most Component and when loaded you can update the status **fontLoaded:true**
in the global state [Redux].

It is well explained by me on medium [Refer This](https://medium.com/@piyushgupta_81472/using-custom-fonts-in-expo-the-best-way-81f0e785580c)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know the thread is old but this may helps others too. The direct use `Font.asyncLoad()` cause the **system font error**.

> fontFamily "roboto-medium" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        assetsLoaded: false,
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        await Font.loadAsync({
            'roboto-medium': require('./assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf')
        });

        this.setState({ assetsLoaded: true });
    }

    render() {

        const {assetsLoaded} = this.state;

        if( assetsLoaded ) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.heading}>Custom Roboto Font</Text>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 40}}>Default Font</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                    <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

If you like to know more in detail then please follow the link.

https://webomnizz.com/add-custom-font-to-react-native-using-expo/

Answer (score 0):

Im using this method with Expo react native:
first install the relative npm packages, in my case im using "tajawal" font

```
npm i @expo-google-fonts/tajawal
```

**in App.js:**

```
let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Tajawal_300Light,
    Tajawal_400Regular,
    Tajawal_500Medium,
    Tajawal_800ExtraBold,
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }
```

Then use "TajawalFontFamily" font as a normal fontFamily style in any component

```
style={{fontFamily:TajawalFontFamily }}
```